# Respond with two files data on readFile - Node

Tags: node.js, response, readfile

I'm using node to respond clients with two files. For now, i'm using a endpoint for each file, cause i can't figure out how pass more than one in a row.

Here's the function that responds with the file:

```
    exports.chartBySHA1 = function (req, res, next, id) {

        var dir = './curvas/' + id + '/curva.txt'; // id = 1e4cf04ad583e483c27b40750e6d1e0302aff058
        fs.readFile(dir, function read(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(400).send("Não foi possível buscar a curva.");
            }
            content = data;
            res.status(200).send(content);
        });
    };
```

Besides that, i need to change the default name of the file, when i reach that endpoint, the name brings 1e4cf04ad583e483c27b40750e6d1e0302aff058, but i'm passing the content of 'curva.txt'.

Someone has any tips?

Comment: Are you expecting the files to be saved separately on the client, or as one big file?

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** How do I pass back contents of more than one file back to a user without having to create individual endpoints.

**A:** There are a few ways you can do this.

If the content of each file is not huge then the easiest way out is to read in all of the contents and then transmit them back as a `javascript` key-value object. E.g.

```
let data = {
    file1: "This is some text from file 1",
    file2: "Text for second file"
}

res.send(data);
res.end();
```

If the content is particularly large then you can stream the data across to the client, while doing so you could add some metadata or `hints` to tell the client what they are going to receive in the next moment and when is the end of file.

There is probably some libraries which can do the latter for you already, so I would suggest you shop around in `github` before designing/writing your own.

The former method is the easiest.